# MySQL counting duplicates in group concat

Tags: mysql

This are my results after executing my query:

```
S-029-45,S-029-45BEFR
S-035-45,S-035-45FR,S-029-45,S-029-45FR
S-035-45,S-035-45DE,S-035-45,S-035-45DE
S-029-45,S-029-45DE,C-003-DACH
```

I want to get only the 3 row. Because `S-035-45` appears twice . To get this rows I used the `GROUP_CONCAT`(my_colum_name).

My query looks like:

```
select group_concat (my_colum_name)
from my table
group by order_id
```

How can I have displayed only the 3 row in my case? I want to get all of data where I have 2 duplicates were found. How can I do that ?  I cannot use the where condition like where mycolumnname = 'S-035-45'. These data are dynamic.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join with a query that counts the number of repetitions of `my_column_name` and returns the `order_id` where the count is exactly 2.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(my_column_name)
FROM my_table AS t1
JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT order_id
      FROM (SELECT order_id, my_column_name
            FROM my_table
            GROUP BY order_id, my_column_name
            HAVING COUNT(*) = 2) AS x) AS t2
ON t1.order_id = t2.order_id
GROUP BY t1.order_id
```

Comment: simple great answer , thnx a lot :)